# How to invoke a method on an Option in scala only if the entry exists (is not None)

Tags: scala

Consider:

```
class Foo {
  def bar() = println("bar")
}
val fooOpt = Option[Foo]
```

The following should be (is??) a simple construct in Scala but it has so far eluded me.

```
fooOpt.getOrElse(None).<logic to invoke if exists>(_.bar)
```

Note : I need the logic to be ***inline***  and *not* something like

```
if (fooOpt.isDefined) { fooOpt.get.bar }
```

The point is to achieve a builder pattern/structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
foo.foreach(_.bar)
```

Alternatively, if you want to transform the value inside the `Option` into something else, use `map` instead:

```
foo.map(_bar)
```

Not sure if that's what you want, though.

Comment: Fair enough - at least the `foreach` does take care of the `Option` consideration.  I'm looking for a transformation e.g. a map kind of operation.   flatMap is *not* it - i.e.   `flatMap(_.bar)`.  But the `flatMap` is heading the direction desired.

Comment: Then I'm not sure I understand you: you write this `fooOpt.getOrElse(None)` which looks kinda wrong, since fooOpt is already an `Option` and perhaps you got confused with the type-dangerous nature of `getOrElse`, which in this case returns `Object` since that's the only common type of `Foo` and `Option[Nothing]`. Maybe you can provide a more detailed example of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: You can use `map` with the same purpose as `foreach`, just that with `map` you can DO something with the return value (e.g. map it to smth else). From your example, it seemed to me you didn't want to use it.

Comment: Also if extracting a value, consider `fold`. `Some(foo).fold(42)(_.bar)`.

Comment: _-Why `map`?_ asked the young grasshopper. _-Because an `Option` is conceptually nothing but a specialized list - one with either exactly 0 (None) or 1 (Some) items in it._

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear, is this what you are looking for?

```
foo.map(_.bar)
```